# Accept gzip encoding using httr R

Tags: r, node.js, json, httr

I subscribe to a financial data provider ORATS. The software engineer reached out to me to let me know my GET() requests are timing out. He said to allow gzip encoding in my GET() request header. The SWE does not code in R and has sent me some node.js code to lean on.

I thought the httr GET() request automatically compressed the files to gzip.

Below is the node.js code provided by the SWE followed by my current R code that worked until I increased the size of the file I am pulling from their API (starting to time out).

```
const request = require('request');

const options = {
  url: 'https://api.orats.io/data/cores/general?include=earn',
  headers: {
  'Authorization' : 'your authorization token',
  'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip'
  },
  gzip : true
};

request(options, function(err, response, body){
// Body is already uncompressed b/c the request library uncompresses it for you.
console.log(JSON.parse(body));
});


R code:
library(httr)
x = GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = token))
y = rawToChar(x$content)
```

I would like this code to request the gziped file. 
Thank you.

Comment: What prevents you from adding `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip" to your httr GET request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the same `Accept-Encoding` line to the httr GET request as well:

```
library(httr)
x = GET(url, add_headers(.headers = c('Authorization'= token,
                                      'Accept-Encoding' = 'gzip, deflate')))
```

Note that [httr automatically decompresses the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592065/httr-and-accept-encoding-gzip-deflate/56106329#56106329).

Comment: would I not expect the gzip call to run faster? They both have the same exact elapsed time. Is there a way to see that it properly compressed the file? Thanks

Comment: You can check this using one of the methods mentioned in [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/621227/check-if-http-calls-are-gzipped).

Comment: Note that it might very well be that the request is using gzip independently of whether you specify it. You can check this inspecting the httr request. See [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) for more information on how to inspect the header of an httr request.